# RAID 10 Cluster Size for SQL Dynamics AX Database

Tags: sql-server, hyper-v, hp, storage-area-network, hp-proliant

Many article read and many websites visited yet still no closer to a firm or concrete answer.
We have created all our Arrays for our SQL 2012 installation with the appropriate LUN's and understand that the VHDx files should be formatted in 64kb cluster size. This is fine.

However, the question is what do you advise the stripe size at the RAID controller level should be?
Few articles say go with the default at 64k and others say go for something a little bigger like 128k or 254k. After basic file testing we found that 128k was yielding better results however this is specific to file handling and not necessarily SQL server load.

The database will mainly be doing more writing then reading.

Thanks

Inventory: HP P2000, DL380 G8 connected via iSCSI (10gbps), sql to be virtulised, windows clustering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

256k+ - SQL Server, at least enterprise, tries to do IO in this size and allocate clusters (64kb, 8 pages of 8kb) in groups of 4 to optimize IO.

So, cluster size should be multiple of 256kb.